# todo mvc ember app error - Unexpected token <

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I am trying to learn ember.js using the online tutorials http://emberjs.com/guides/getting-started/

I reached this step http://emberjs.com/guides/getting-started/creating-a-new-model/ and here is the application.

https://github.com/42races/ember-apps/tree/master/todomvc

At this point I am not able to proceed, am getting an error and not able to proceed, here is
a screenshot of the error I am getting.[image: screenshot]

How do I proceed? Please someone help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You script tag is missing a /, in index.html

```
<script>
```

to

```
</script>
```

Comment: thanks @MartinElvar, I really need some tool to check my html code to escape from such stupid mistakes

Comment: Common typing mistake really, but the error message doesn't really help much, so it can be hard to figure. :)